# How to Decrypt RSA encrypted string from JSEncrypt using C# BouncyCastle

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I know there are a few posts regarding this, but none of them solve my issue so i will cut to the chase.

I have encrypted a string using JSEncrypt (javascript) with the following code:

```
var rsa = new JSEncrypt();
rsa.setPublicKey(pubKey);
var encrypted = rsa.encrypt($(this).text());
```

The public key is stored in a var like so:

```
var pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\
    MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCkskeHcz6zTvnXKGHbCkfeEnKF\
    38j1hEgWw9UAZlg5a7m/1AaHkqkvKUOfoX+zSYH4CJr/MEVmrEa2ucPjKljXK14M\
    74NzSwYuPxaikpfwxe7qvn1/0TIqahVHEiSmqieLIl+gHIyAc32e/wUyjhGFjbwL\
    eJ/hBDTkt6O/QajWKwIDAQAB\
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

I then use the generated cipher text and send that to c# where it needs to decrypt it. I am using Bouncy Castle and have written code as such:

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

    using (var reader = File.OpenText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/scripts/private.pem"))
    {
        keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
    }
    var engine = new RsaEngine();
    engine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);

    var decrypted = engine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length);
    var decryptedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
    return decryptedMessage;
}
```

It does the decryption without error, but the output looks like this:

```
"\u0002��lT�J;�ol�\u008fY�L:GK=\u0002�(�����\\\u0003ܢ�fMT�\u001eoqR�\\\u000f�s�A��+ښ�|����\u0001J�s�w[\u001egſ\u0012^7�\u000f44Qy\a*�T�~Tu�Ei�O/<�\u000f!S:�]\u0018V<7S\n:x@���GȀ\u0016.w���Lb�\0"
```

I have tried to specifically use PKSC#1 by having this:

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

    using (var reader = File.OpenText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/scripts/private.pem"))
    {
        keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
    }
    Pkcs1Encoding engine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
    engine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);

    var decrypted = engine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length);
    var decryptedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
    return decryptedMessage;
 }
```

I clearly have something wrong here as the decryptedMessage = "" and the decrypted bytes = bytes[0]

How do i fix this so that it decrypts the cipherText correctly.

As far i know JSEncrypt encrypts using PKSC1 encoding as default?

Any help is appreciated.

Please avoid rude comments, as learning to do it correctly is why I am posting here.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: The \u00 bits look suspiciously like unicode encoded characters, and encoding issues are a common encryption/decryption issue. So somewhere in your chain there is likely an encoding problem. It could simply be the display cannot show the decrypted value.

Comment: doesn't JSEncrypt return encrypted results with base64 encoding? If so you have to base64 decode it first.

Comment: @JamesKPolk i am using : var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText) to remove the base64 encoding.

Comment: @dbugger I had originally thought of this too, what i then did was wrote an encryption function in C#, similar to the decryption one in the question and i encrypted the same string "Test" and when using the decryption function it returned "Test" as expected. I'm thinking this must be something to do with the different method of encryption?